# mouse scroll wheel function not working in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have linked the jquery.mousewheel file in the head of the html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Is there anything else I need to do to make the function work?

Additional details:

I am also getting this error while validating with w3c.[Bad value gallery01 for attribute rel on element a: Keyword gallery01 is not registered. - HTML5]. Could this be probably the reason.

```
<!--jquery ui tabs containing fancybox-->
            <div id="portfolio-list">
              <div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#graphic-design">Graphic Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#web-design">Web Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#3d">3d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#flash">Flash</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div id="graphic-design">




                        <!--gallery 01 -->
<a class="fancybox" href="img/colorful-abstract.jpg" rel="gallery01"><img src="img/navigation/about.png" alt=""/></a>
<a class="fancybox" href="img/grunge-texture.jpg" rel="gallery01"><img src="img/navigation/contact.png" alt=""/></a>




                   </div>

                    <div id="web-design">
                        <a class="fancybox" href="img/grunge-texture.jpg" rel="gallery01"><img src="img/navigation/contact.png" alt=""/></a>

                    </div>

                    <div id="3d">

                    </div>

                    <div id="flash">

                    </div>

              </div>


            </div>
```

jquery code:
// fancybox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true,
        'cyclic'        :   true,
        'showNavArrows' :   true,
        'showCloseButton': false,
        'titleFormat'   : formatTitle,
        'titlePosition' :   'over',
        'onComplete'    :   function() {
        $("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
            $("#fancybox-title").show();
        }, function() {
            $("#fancybox-title").hide();
        });
    }
    })
});
```

Comment: the solution to what? You haven't said what your problem is. "It doesn't work" is not enough if you want to get help.

Comment: +1 the best way to get help is to provide detailed information of the issue and preferably a link with a sample of the issue. the problem could be something different from what you describe but it's hard to say if we don't see it... we could only guess then.

Comment: I have added some additional detail plz check above.

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is that you cannot scroll down or up while you're on mouse over the fancybox window, you can solve that by removing completely the jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4 script.

For the invalidation of your rel attribute, it seems like HTML5 standards are really stricts with this issue, there are a limit of words you can really use there. I recommend you reading this post:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes

Answer (score 0):

this code working fine for me. Use **mousewheel()** but with in event **trigger('click')**

```
<div id="view_more_filter" style="height:1000px;">scroll testing...</div>
    <div id="show_more_fltr">   
        <a<span>More Filter</span></a>   
      </div>

    <script>
        var mod_width = '500';
        var mod_height = '520';
             $('#show_more_fltr a').click(function(e){
                $('#show_more_fltr').fancybox({
                     autoDimensions: false,
                     width        : mod_width,
                     height      : mod_height,
                     scrolling : 'auto',
                     href : "#view_more_filter",
                }).trigger('click');
                $('#fancybox-outer').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    $('#fancybox-wrap').trigger('mousewheel.fb', delta);
                                 });
            });
    </script>
```